# Are there an infinite number of sequal BOX QUEST games?

Tags: succubox

When I reach Level 100 there's an item in the shop which is *"???"* which requires 101 levels and when I get this (spending my 101 levels) it starts to build Anticipation.

When Anticipation hits 10 I get another shop item called *"Back Box Quest 2 on Kickstarter"* and the Anticipation builds faster. When it gets over 1 sexdecillion I get another item *"Increase Box Quest 2 Kicstarter Pledge"* which against build Anticipation much much faster. When it hits Infinity I get *"IT'S HERE!!!"* and the pages seems to reload but now it's BOX QUEST 2 that I buy.

I am up to BOX QUEST 8 and I am wondering, is this just an infinite loop? or is there a final BOX QUEST game and if so, what number is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no max.

The code just checks if you're level 100 (`data.level.value >= 100`), if you can pay 101 levels (`new Cost(data.level,101)`), and if your anticipation is infinity (`data.anticipation.value >= 1e51`).

Then it calls `Ascend()` which just adds one to your "ascension" (`window.localStorage["ascension"] = JSON.stringify(ascensionlevel + 1)`).

Then the next thing is you buy `"BOX QUEST " + F(ascensionlevel)`.

You can keep going as long as your patience allows.